# If $a \in \mathbb{F}_q$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $x^{q^n}-x+na$ is divisible by $x^q-x+ a$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Tags: finite-fields

If $\beta$ is root $x^q-x+a$ then $\beta^q-\beta \in \mathbb{F}_q$. I thought about the frobenius map but could not get anywhere. Would you please help me with the remaining?

Comment: Is $\;q\;$ a prime? A power of prime? None...?

Comment: $q$ is a prime power.

Comment: Have you tried to prove by induction that every root of $X^q-X+a$ is a root of $X^{q^n}-X+na$?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I was looking for more concrete solution.

Comment: "More concrete"? Like what, say? Induction looks to me as concrete as one could reasonable expect...

Comment: And once you have used @DonAntonio 's method, you'll need one more thing to complete the problem: show that the roots of $X^q-X+a$ are distinct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\;\beta^q-\beta=-a\iff \beta^a=\beta-a\in\Bbb F_q\;$ , then

$$-a=(-a)^q=(\beta^q-\beta)^q=\beta^{q^2}-\beta^q=\beta^{q^2}-\beta+a\implies\beta^{q^2}-\beta+2a=0$$

and there you have the hint (first non-trivial example) for proving inductively that $\;\beta\;$ root of $\;\beta^q-\beta+a\implies\beta\;$ root of $\;\beta^{q^n}-\beta+na\;$

Comment: $\beta$ is a root of $\beta^q -\beta +a$ implies $\beta$ is a root of $\beta^{q^n} -\beta +na$. This is fine. But is this conform that $x^q - x + a$ divides $x^{q^n} - x + na$ over $F_q$? I am not sure. Any suggestion please?